# Accessing advanced agendas

Tags: android-netrunner

Say a runner accesses an agenda that already has advancement counters on it, but hasn't been scored. As well as the runner stealing the agenda, what happens to the tokens? Are they trashed, or stolen as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They would be trashed as well.  The runner has no use for those tokens, since they add the agenda to their scored point total as soon as they access it.